# ListView Custom adapter TextView initialize inside try catch block not showing

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Trying to fetch data from SQLite and initialize some text view data but the problem is that text view does not show the data that initialize inside the try-catch block. Is there any better solution to accomplish this problem?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    AdmissionViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.followup_listview_row_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new AdmissionViewHolder();
        viewHolder.p_type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.p_type);
        viewHolder.pName_Age = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.p_name_age);
        viewHolder.admissionDateTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.admission_date_time);
        viewHolder.facilityName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.facility_name);
        viewHolder.sex = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sex);
        viewHolder.followup_Item = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.followup);
        viewHolder.followupItem = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.followup_item);
        viewHolder.itemInfo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_info);
        viewHolder.arrow = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.arrow_button);
        viewHolder.hiddenView = (TableLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.hiddenView);
        viewHolder.ps_m = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_pm);
        viewHolder.ps_e = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_pe);
        viewHolder.ps_n = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_pn);
        viewHolder.ts_m = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_tm);
        viewHolder.ts_e = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_te);
        viewHolder.ts_n = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_s_tn);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (AdmissionViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    AdmissionModel admissionModel = getItem(position);
    String pAge = String.format("%dy %dm %dd",admissionModel.AgeYears,admissionModel.AgeMonths,admissionModel.AgeDays);
    viewHolder.p_type.setText(admissionModel.PtType);
    viewHolder.pName_Age.setText(String.format("%s (%s)",admissionModel.PtName,pAge));
    viewHolder.admissionDateTime.setText(String.format("%s %s",admissionModel.HosAdmDate,admissionModel.HosAdmTime));
    viewHolder.facilityName.setText(admissionModel.FacilityName);
    viewHolder.sex.setText(admissionModel.SexName);
    viewHolder.itemInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.itemInfo.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.followupItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.followupItem.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.followup_Item.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.followup_Item.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.arrow.setOnClickListener(v -> clickedListener.buttonClicked(admissionModel));
    viewHolder.arrow.setTag(position);

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        String toDay = formatter.format(date);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        String previousDay = formatter.format(cal.getTime());

        List<FollowupModel> followupModelList = dbHelper.GetFollowupData(admissionModel.NtfSL,previousDay,toDay);

        if(followupModelList.size()>0){
            Map<String, List<FollowupModel>> groupByDateList = Stream.of(followupModelList).collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(e->e.FollowupDateyyyMMdd));

            for (String dataKey : groupByDateList.keySet()){
                if(dataKey.equals(previousDay)){
                    for (FollowupModel followupModel : groupByDateList.get(dataKey)){
                        if(followupModel.Type == 1){
                            viewHolder.ps_m = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }else if(followupModel.Type == 2){
                            viewHolder.ps_e = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }else if(followupModel.Type == 3){
                            viewHolder.ps_n = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }
                    }
                }else if(dataKey.equals(toDay)){
                    for (FollowupModel followupModel : groupByDateList.get(dataKey)){
                        if(followupModel.Type == 1){
                            viewHolder.ts_m  = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }else if(followupModel.Type == 2){
                            viewHolder.ts_e = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }else if(followupModel.Type == 3){
                            viewHolder.ts_n = setPatientStatus(followupModel.PtStatus);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(admissionModel.isTableLayoutVisible){
        viewHolder.hiddenView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_expand_less_24);
    }else{
        viewHolder.hiddenView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_expand_more_24);
    }

    return row;
}
```

Comment: And what does `e.printStackTrace()` say ?? Adding heavy code into methods alike `onBindViewholder()` is usually decremental for the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here getView() will be called every time when your layout is inflated .
Below line is heavy operation .

```
    List<FollowupModel> followupModelList = dbHelper.GetFollowupData(admissionModel.NtfSL,previousDay,toDay);
```

You will have to move this to other class and pass required info as a parameter/list to your custom adapter class

Comment: I am already passing a list when the adapter called, I need some additional data to show that's why I use that line. If you have any better solution please let me know.

public FollowupListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<AdmissionModel> items,ClickedListener clickedListener) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        fruitList = items;
        this.clickedListener = clickedListener;
    }